# How to make UPDATE ... SET MAX (column, 5) in tarantool

Tags: lua, tarantool

Actually, there is a task-to collect usage statistics from the fields: `cnt`, `value`, `max`, `min`

I wanted to do everything in one run `upsert`. `cnt` set via `+`, `value` via `=`

I don't understand how to make the min field:

1. Is there a simple option to make your own function for `upsert` (lua, which would get the old and new values and output the result)
2. Or I can make the function that will get the entire tuple, new data, and update the corresponding values itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the `before_replace` trigger to space, which returns a new value if the old value is missing, otherwise it returns a modified one. About like this:

```
function trigger_before_update_space1 (old, new)
    return old and box.tuple.new({
        new[1],
        new[2],
        math.max(old[3], new[2])
    }) or new
end
```